# vertex normal for triangles of dodecahedron

Tags: 3d, directx, directx-9, vertex, normals

I want to initialize vertex normal for using lighting, but I dont know how to accomplish this.

Below is the program I have made using directx 9 and C++.  It simulates a simple planet orbit without implementing lighting and without vertex normal too.

what i need is the vertex normal in the vertices array and initialize indices array

```
  // include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file 
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <windowsx.h>
  #include <d3d9.h>
  #include <d3dx9.h> 
  #include <math.h>


  // define the screen resolution
  #define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
  #define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

  // include the Direct3D Library files
 #pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
  #pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

  // global declarations
  LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;
  LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
 LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the vertex buffer
   LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the index buffer

  // function prototypes
  void initD3D(HWND hWnd);
  void render_frame(void);
  void cleanD3D(void);
  void init_graphics(void);

   struct CUSTOMVERTEX {FLOAT X, Y, Z; DWORD COLOR;};
   #define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE )

   // the WindowProc function prototype
   LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


  // the entry point for any Windows program
   int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow)
  {
  HWND hWnd;
  WNDCLASSEX wc;

   ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

  RegisterClassEx(&wc);

  hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"WindowClass", L"Our Direct3D Program",
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                      NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

  initD3D(hWnd);

  MSG msg;

   while(TRUE)
   {
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;

    render_frame();
  }

   cleanD3D();

  return msg.wParam;
 }


   // this is the main message handler for the program
  LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
  switch(message)
  {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;
  }

   return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   }


    // this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
    void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
    {
   d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

     D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

     ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
     d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

   d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                  D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                  hWnd,
                  D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                  &d3dpp,
                  &d3ddev);

    init_graphics();

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
     d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);    // turn off culling
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer
   }


    // this is the function used to render a single frame
   void render_frame(void)
   {
   d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
  d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

   d3ddev->BeginScene();

    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

   // set the view transform
   D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix
   D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
   &D3DXVECTOR3 (1.0f, 9.0f, 50.0f),    // the camera position
   &D3DXVECTOR3 (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),      // the look-at position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f));    // the up direction
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView 

   // set the projection transform
   D3DXMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix
   D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                           D3DXToRadian(60),    // the horizontal field of view
                           (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
                           1.0f,   // the near view-plane
                           100.0f);    // the far view-plane
   d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection); // set the projection

   // set the world transform
   static float index = 0.0f; index+=0.03f; // an ever-increasing float value
   D3DXMATRIX matRotateY;    // a matrix to store the rotation for each triangle
D3DXMATRIX matTranslateX_venus;
D3DXMATRIX matTranslateX_merkurius;
D3DXMATRIX matTranslateX_sun;
D3DXMATRIX matScale_merkurius;
D3DXMATRIX matScale_sun;
D3DXMATRIX matTranslateX_earth;
D3DXMATRIX matTranslateX_mars;

  D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, index);    // the rotation matrix
   D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslateX_venus,16.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslateX_earth,24.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslateX_mars,32.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
   D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslateX_merkurius,8.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
   D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslateX_sun,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
   D3DXMatrixScaling(&matScale_merkurius, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&matScale_sun, 2.5f, 2.5f, 2.5f);
   // set the world transform


  // select the vertex buffer to display
  d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
  d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);

   // draw the pyramid

  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matScale_sun*matTranslateX_sun *matRotateY)); 
    d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 12, 0, 20);


  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTranslateX_venus * matRotateY)); 
  d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 12, 0, 12, 0, 20);

  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matScale_merkurius*matTranslateX_merkurius
    *         matRotateY));
  d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 24, 0, 12, 0, 20);

   d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTranslateX_earth * matRotateY));
  d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 36, 0, 12, 0, 20);

   d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTranslateX_mars * matRotateY));
  d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 48, 0, 12, 0, 20);
   d3ddev->EndScene(); 

   d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  }


  // this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
  void cleanD3D(void)
  {
    v_buffer->Release();
    i_buffer->Release();
    d3ddev->Release();
  d3d->Release();
  }


   // this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
   void init_graphics(void)
  {
// create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX
float t = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
struct CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
{
    {-1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), }, 
    {1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {-1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {0, -1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {0, 1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {0, -1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {0, 1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {-t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },
    {-t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,0), },

    {-1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), }, 
    {1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {-1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {0, -1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {0, 1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {0, -1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {0, 1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {-t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },
    {-t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(88,90,97), },

    {-1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), }, 
    {1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {-1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {0, -1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {0, 1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {0, -1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {0, 1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {-t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },
    {-t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(136,108,57), },

    {-1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), }, 
    {1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {-1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {0, -1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {0, 1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {0, -1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {0, 1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {-t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },
    {-t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(14,51,180), },

    {-1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), }, 
    {1, t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {-1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {1, -t, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {0, -1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {0, 1, t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {0, -1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {0, 1, -t, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {-t, 0, -1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },
    {-t, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(192,49,1), },


};

// create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(60*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                           0,
                           CUSTOMFVF,
                           D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                           &v_buffer,
                           NULL);

   VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

  // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
  v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
   memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
  v_buffer->Unlock();

   // create the indices using an int array
   short indices[] =
  {
  // 5 faces around p0
  0, 11, 5,
  0, 5, 1,
  0, 1, 7,
  0, 7, 10,
  0, 10, 11,
   // 5 adjacent faces
   1, 5, 9,
   5, 11, 4,
   11, 10, 2,
  10, 7, 6,
   7, 1, 8,
    // 5 faces around point p3
  3, 9, 4,
  3, 4, 2,
  3, 2, 6,
  3, 6, 8,
  3, 8, 9,
  // 5 adjacent faces
  4, 9, 5,
  2, 4, 11,
 6, 2, 10,
  8, 6, 7,
  9, 8, 1
  };

  // create a index buffer interface called i_buffer
 d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(60*sizeof(short),
                      0,
                      D3DFMT_INDEX16,
                      D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                      &i_buffer,
                      NULL);

  // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
  i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
 memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
  i_buffer->Unlock(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. Calculate the vertex normals yourself and add it to your vertex declaration. in this case you would have to draw each face separatedly since a vertex is share by more than one face. so totally you need 12(faces) * 5(each face have 5 vertcies) = 60 vertices. the vertices on the same face has the same normals, so you would have to calculate 12 normals totally.
2. Create a [D3DXMesh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by [D3DXCreateMeshFVF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and call [D3DXComputeNormals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to let Direct3D calculate the normals for you.

To use lighting in Direct3D

1. Enable lighting.
2. Define vertex with normals(or without if you use option 2).
3. Create light and materials(materials describes how your surface will reflect the light)
4. Set light and materials.

reference for [Dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)

Comment: i cant use mesh sir. i must calculate it. so can you teach me how to calculate it. please give me an example from my code.